# Replace specified letters with randomly selected strings from an array dedicated to the found letter

Tags: php, arrays, random, replace, mapping

I have a few letters; for example a, b, c, d and e.

For each one of them, I have sets of two-character values like this:

a -> fg, dz, gc, bg

b -> zt, hg, oq, vg, gb

c -> lt, pr, cs, sh, pr

d -> kt, nt, as, pr

e -> zd, ke, cg, sq, mo, ld

Here comes the question:

I would like to get a random value for each time for example: `dcbae`
and for this the ultimate output should be something like this: `ntshztdzld` or `asltvggcmo`, etc.

(After generating a random string with the characters above (between a-e), it should generate another string that contains random values those are related with the each character.

Comment: Encryption is not random

Comment: sorry my bad. buti hope you got the idea.

Comment: @ColeJohnson OTPs beg to differ.

Comment: Encryption is not random, but this looks like a simple substition cipher on a message consisting of random characters within an alphabet. Maybe if we knew what it is that it is supposed to achieve ...

Comment: I hope you only write this for fun. Your encryption scheme is very weak.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Most encryption schemes consume some per-message randomness, namely the IV. Per block randomness is unusual, since it bloats the ciphertext. But it is an improvement over a simple substitution cipher.

Comment: OFC its for fun :) If it wasnt for fun, i wouldnt dare to write in here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you would first create a map:

```
$map = Array(
    "a" => Array("fg","dz","gc","bg"),
    "b" => Array("zt","hg","oq","vg","gb"),
    "c" => Array("lt","pr","cs","sh","pr"),
    "d" => Array("kt","nt","as","pr"),
    "e" => Array("zd","ke","cg","sq","mo","ld")
);
```

I notice that you have the same pair "pr" several times - if you want this encoding to be reversible, avoid duplicates.

Anyway, once you have that it's easy enough to loop through your input string and get a random output:

```
$input = "dcbae";
$len = strlen($input);
$output = "";
for( $i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $entry = &$map[$input[$i]];
    if( isset($entry)) $output .= $entry[mt_rand(0,count($entry)-1)];
    else $output .= "??";
}
```

`$output` is the result.

Comment: Thank you and yes. That repeat was my mistake. There should't be any pair in diferent arrays. Btw, input should be self-generated as well.

Comment: @galymzhan but not cyptographically secure, and neither is the substitution cipher, given enough ciphertext/plain text

Comment: @owlstead I'm not talking about security, `mt_rand` provides better distribution of random values and has a very long period

Comment: Just a tip: Instead of `$entry[mt_rand(...)]` I'd rather use `$entry[array_rand($entry)]`. It's a more specific function that makes it slightly easier to understand.

Comment: In general `mt_rand` is not fit for crypto. But since the OP's scheme is so weak, it doesn't really matter anymore. If you'd use `mt_rand` when answering a question that uses crypto to achieve security, I'd downvote for it.

Comment: @galymzhan using mt_rand is fine as long as you don't expect it to be secure, but as it is used for encryption purposes I felt obliged to mention this - it's perfectly fine for what I hope is a bit of practice

Comment: Thank you guys. Much appriciated. Btw, how can i make it $input self-generated within the letters those in array? I don't want to put values everytime that i run this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Setup matching values
$encpairs[ 'a' ] = array( 'fg', 'dz', 'gc', 'bg' );
$encpairs[ 'b' ] = array( 'zt', 'hg', 'oq', 'vg', 'gb' );
$encpairs[ 'c' ] = array( 'lt', 'pr', 'cs', 'sh', 'pr' );
// etc. etc.

// Define input string
$my_string = 'abc';

// To randomly build input string
$my_string = '';
$last_key = '';
$key = '';
$keys = array_keys( $encpairs );
$ttl_keys = count( $keys ) -1;

// Generate the input string at random; change "5" to length you desire
for ( $j=0; $j < 5; $j++ ){
    // Randomly select a key from $encpairs array (giving you one letter at random)
    // The while loop ensures no two letters are used consecutively
    while ( $key == $last_key ) {
        $key =$keys[ rand(0, $ttl_keys ) ];
    }
    $last_key = $key;
    $my_string .= $key;
}

// Determine input string length
$length = strlen( $my_string );

// Loop through each letter
$output = '';
for( $i=0; $i < $length; $i++ ){
    shuffle( $encpairs[ $my_string[$i] ] );
    $output.= $encpairs[ $my_string[$i] ][0]; // Added [0]
}
```

Comment: My mistake, the second-to-last line should have had [0] appended :)

Comment: Thanks. May be i am being a douchebag but i have last two things..
First, how can i make the $my_string self-generated within the letters that i put in array? (between abc for example)
Second, is there a way to prevent the repeations when we generating the $my_string? abc bca bac cba cab is ok.. but aac bab cac is not..

Comment: Sure thing, I updated my answer to reflect the two requests... let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: thank you very much and much appriciated. second one doesnt work at all.. e.g. gagabga -> lkdzlkdzoquhfg
i put only 7 letters to array list.. in this case, everyone of them should be used for once if i try to generate a 7-character long input string.. but as you can see there are letters that repeated even 3 times..

Comment: You said in your comment above that "abc bca bac cba cab is ok" so the code allows repeated letters, just not in a row, preventing i.e. "aac", "abb", "acacc", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Start by initializing a second string outside of the loop. Convert your original string (to be encrypted) into an array, and then loop through the whole array and append to the second string.
So you get

```
$splitstr=str_split($original);
$final_string="";
$map=Array(/**/);
foreach($splitstr as $char)
{
  $final_string.=$map[$char][rand(0,count($map[$char])-1)];
}
return $final_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This task doesn't absolutely demand a `preg_` function call, but there are some advantages in doing so.  Because the randomized translations need to build a new string, `preg_replace_callback()` doesn't require manual concatenation to the result string.  Ideally, whatever process you decide to use should be robust enough that future maintenance will only require the lookup array to be updated -- the processing scripting should remain the same.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IHEa8))

```
$map = [
    'a' => ['fg', 'dz', 'gc', 'bg'],
    'b' => ['zt', 'hg', 'oq', 'vg', 'gb'],
    'c' => ['lt', 'pr', 'cs', 'sh', 'pr'],
    'd' => ['kt', 'nt', 'as', 'pr'],
    'e' => ['zd', 'ke', 'cg', 'sq', 'mo', 'ld'],
];

$subpattern = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', array_keys($map)));

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '#' . $subpattern . '#',
         fn($m) => $map[$m[0]][array_rand($map[$m[0]])],
         'dddcbae'
     );
```